# Multi language for a Website (php and javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i try to build a language selection for my Website.

I use php and Javascript.

My idea is to create for every language a php file.

**For example: lang_en.php**

```
<?php
 $lang = array();
 $lang[1] = "Everything is ok!";
 $lang[2] = "Please select a Number.";
?>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  lang = new Array();
  lang[1] = 'Hello, please select a Button.';
  lang[2] = 'Are you sure?';    
</script>
```

But i am not sure, is this a good solution? Or is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!
Peter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please please please [don't make up](http://php.net/manual/en/book.gettext.php) your [own solutions](http://code.google.com/p/gettext-js/). You'll never get it as right as something that already exists.

Answer (score 3):

Solutions for your problem already exist, you might want to look into **gettext**

Here is a tutorial on how to use it with php: http://mel.melaxis.com/devblog/2005/08/06/localizing-php-web-sites-using-gettext/